# "Effected a change in" vs. "Effected a change on"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

The sentence is:

The longer seasons effected a change in/on the ecosystems around the lake.

Which is the correct usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when English talks about a change of something, it prefers *in* to *on* by roughly two orders of magnitude. You may check the Ngram viewer to compare *effected changes in* with *effected changes on* or use the google with search terms "changes in" and "changes on". (Insert the usual caveats here.) The prepositional preference reverses in two situations. The first is illustrated in [*Gamonia, Or, The Art of Preserving Game*](https://books.google.com/books?id=61QEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8stLl-7bSAhVDxCYKHWe8AwQ4ChDoAQhKMAk#v=onepage&q=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&f=false) by L Rawstorne and T J Rawlins

> There may have been convulsions of the earth operating powerfully; the great deluge, or, as some suppose, a succession of deluges, may have **effected changes on** its surface;....

When the change is to the surface of something (literally or figuratively), *on* will be used to avoid an inapt reference to the interior the thing that was changed.

Here are some further illustrations:

- steel plates

  > [Another producer, Armco Steel Corp., on May 1, **effected changes on sheets,** including hot and cold-rolled, silicon, galvanized, enameling stock and long ternes.](https://books.google.com/books?id=3tQfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&dq=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj586SDgbfSAhUJRCYKHXX0D5QQ6AEIIzAB)
- the platform of a theater:

  > [The Stasi certainly criticized many aspects of the BE's [The Berliner Ensemble's] output over the years, yet there is little evidence to suggest that it **effected changes on stage** directly.](https://books.google.com/books?id=4yKTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA314&dq=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA056ggrfSAhVCRiYKHevJAr04ChDoAQg5MAY#v=onepage&q=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&f=false)
- steps of a hierarchy

  > [The assemblies **effected changes on a local level**, subject to the approbation of the king through his various administrators.](https://books.google.com/books?id=0eR78sYhgJcC&pg=PA120&dq=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA056ggrfSAhVCRiYKHevJAr04ChDoAQhFMAg#v=onepage&q=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&f=false)

The second situation is when the change is imposed. From [*The French Presence in the South Pacific, 1842–1940*](https://books.google.com/books?id=c2euCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&dq=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSzeq_g7fSAhXB5yYKHf_5CDw4FBDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=%22effected%20changes%20on%22&f=false) by R Aldrich:

> Of course, various European agencies **effected changes on the island populations**, and did so with the full force and coercion of colonialism....